# Datalife engine URL's

Tags: php, url, content-management-system

I have **Datalife Engine CMS 10.2 version**. That i want to do change all urls that going like that `index.php?do=register` to `/user/register or something` like that. Thanks for helping and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open .htaccess file in website root and after:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

insert this line:

```
RewriteRule ^user/register$ index.php?do=register [L]
```